# How to give alias to result table of sql which use multiple subqueries?

Tags: mysql, alias

I have a query as below,i want to give a alias name to this result table, so how can I do that?

Here I have used two sub query with union function

```
(
      select op.order_id,op.product_id,op.quantity as ordered_quantity, sum(odp.quantity) as delivered_quantity
      from oops_order_product op 
      left join oops_order_delivery_product odp on odp.product_id = op.product_id and odp.id is null 
      where op.status = 0 
      group by op.product_id
)

union all                                                                                          
(
      SELECT op.order_id,odp.product_id,sum(op.quantity) as ordered_quantity, sum(odp.quantity) as delivered_quantity
      FROM `oops_order_delivery_product` odp
      join oops_order_delivery od on od.id = odp.order_delivery_id
      left join oops_order_product op on op.product_id = odp.product_id and op.id is null
      where odp.status = 0 group by odp.product_id
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly you want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(

      select op.order_id,op.product_id,op.quantity as ordered_quantity, sum(odp.quantity) as delivered_quantity
      from oops_order_product op 
      left join oops_order_delivery_product odp on odp.product_id = op.product_id and odp.id is null 
      where op.status = 0 
      group by op.product_id


      union all                                                                                          

      SELECT op.order_id,odp.product_id,sum(op.quantity) as ordered_quantity,     sum(odp.quantity) as delivered_quantity
      FROM `oops_order_delivery_product` odp
      join oops_order_delivery od on od.id = odp.order_delivery_id
      left join oops_order_product op on op.product_id = odp.product_id and op.id is null
      where odp.status = 0 group by odp.product_id

)
as FinalTable
```